# CSS - Divide width to percentage of parent

Tags: html, css, width, parent

I have given my divs a min-width.

But if the width increases to more that this then the width should be percentage of the parent container.

I can't for the life of me figure out why I am unable to fix this silly thing.

Any help will be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/q6u3sh5f/

In the fiddle above you can see the wrap's white border extends the width of the window but my divs have a mind of their own.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class = "wrap">
      <div class="date">Date</div>
      <div class="month">Month</div>
      <div class="task">Task</div>
      <div class="status">Status</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: #4efa6d;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.date {
  min-width: 60px;
  width: 6.25%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.month {
  min-width: 70px;
  width: 6.25%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.task {
  min-width: 540px;
  width: 67.5%;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.status {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 12.50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: So you need the all the divs to fit in to 100% size?

Comment: You haven't accounted for the margins and borders adding up to more than the remaining %

Comment: 1) the sum of all percentages is lower than 100% but you need to take into account all the margins and you are mixing `px` with `%` 2) the task element has width `auto`. 3) a float clearing should be applied on the parent container

Comment: I did calculate all the widths along with the margin. But when it didn't work I fudged around with the numbers and they probably got messed up then. But yes. All elements that affected the width were considered. @manjuboyz's answere is spot on though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. You can do using `flex`.(hope this is not an issue)
> 2. `float` has become old as of now.
> 3. I have moved `px` to random `%` for `min-width` feel free to modify this.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/gL62yc3p/17/) to playaround.

```css
body {
  background-color: #4efa6d;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display:flex;
}

.date, .month {
  min-width: 2%;
  width: 6.25%; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:5px;
}

.task {
  min-width: 10%;
  width: 67.5%;
  margin: 5px;
 padding:5px; 
  border: 1px solid red;

}

.status {
  min-width: 5%;
  width: 12.5%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class = "wrap">
      <div class="date">Date</div>
      <div class="month">Month</div>
      <div class="task">Task</div>
      <div class="status">Status</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```